# Use In-App Purchase Items Among Multiple Bundle IDs

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I know there are answers to this question out there, but since they're all at least a few years old and I was convince that this changed recently I thought I'd give it a shot:

*Is it possible to share In-App Purchase items among a developer's different bundle IDs?*

We have two different targets in our project that are basically the same app. One is the live version that we submit to the App Store and the other one is a QA version, that we regularly distribute among our developers and testers; we use two different bundle identifiers.

I created a new In-App Purchase item for the live version and I'd like to test it with the other version as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't shared In-App Purchases between different bundle IDs.

> Each developer account can create up to 10,000 in-app purchase products across all the apps in the account. Every product you want to offer in your store must be configured in iTunes Connect. **Because in-app purchase products are associated with a single app**, you create them from the in-app purchase section under Features in iTunes Connect.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/CreatingInAppPurchaseProducts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013727-CH3-SW3

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation!